# Can I use ansible to startup jboss service in domain mode?

Tags: domain-controller, ansible, jboss

I used `sh /usr/local/jboss/bin/domain.sh` manually, and jboss works fine.

When I use ansible to start jboss automatically, jboss log always shows "`Container is down`".

File `/root/startup_jboss.sh` :

```
#!/bin/bash
/bin/sh /usr/local/jboss/bin/domain.sh &
```

My `startup.yml`:

```
---
- name: Tranfser and Execute a script
  hosts: AuditReport

  tasks:
     - name: Tranfser the scipt
       command: chdir=/root /bin/sh startup_jboss.sh
```

I don't know why?

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

Regards,
Cloud

Comment: Why aren't you having `ansible` run the same script that works for you manually?

Comment: Thanks your reply. I found can't use command module(can't run in the backgrond), I tried service module and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you encounter is related to the fact that the context of the execution of the `domain.sh`script is different when you're logged in and when it is executed remotely by Ansible. See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216202/why-does-an-ssh-remote-command-get-fewer-environment-variables-then-when-run-man) for more details.

You need to complete the `/root/startup_jboss.sh`script with the missing environment variables in order to work correctly. You can test it in the same conditions than ansible with a remote SSH command:

`ssh root@<your node> /root/startup_jboss.sh`

You **may** use Ansible to execute a shell script on a remote server but I don't think it's the right solution in your use-case.

Ansible is a Configuration Management tool that is designed to describe **desired states** for your resources (files, process, rights, ...) and ensure **idempotency** (only the changes that are required are done, you can run your script multiple times and you always get the same **state**). In your use-case, you'd like to ensure JBoss is running in domain mode on your remote server. The way I'd tackle it is to encapsulate the `domain.sh` script inside a **init** script to have it running as a **service** and eventually configure this service to run at server startup.
I don't know what is your linux distro but you may have a look [here](https://gist.github.com/lionelg3/3135441) for an example of an `init.d` script for Debian.

In your `startup.yml` playbook you'd first copy the `init.d` script and then ensure your service is running (Ansible provides a [native module to manage services](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I trid to use service, and it works fine. Thanks!!

Comment: Nice! Can I ask you to mark your question as answered by my answer? (see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow) for how-to). THKS.